# Does fish have the colon dash variable operator?

Tags: fish

In bash, I can do

```
$ echo ${undefined:-5}
5
```

to easily deal with unset variables.
Does fish have something like this? Or is there a trick to emulate this? I couldn't find anything after reading https://fishshell.com/docs/current/language.html#parameter-expansion but wanted to double check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No fish doesn't have the expansive parameter expansions of bash.

In this case you can do something like this (yes, it's verbose)

```
set -q undefined; and string length -q $undefined; and echo $undefined; or echo 5
```

Comment: Ever-so-slightly less verbose -- `set -q undefined && test -n $undefined && echo $undefined || echo 5` -- Same effect, right?

Comment: Sure: we can golf one more character off thst using `[ -n $undefined ]`